# Adding Plain SQL Tables to Grails App instead of using ORM?

Tags: sql, grails, ddl

In Grails, how can plain SQL/DDL be used to create / drop tables in the same manner they would be if one were using GORM / ORM?

For example, when using GORM / ORM, the tables used for persistence are regularly created/dropped, and inserted into, during the runtime of Integration Tests, and execution of the application.

I know there is a way to do this using just Groovy as shown in the example named "Advanced Usage" [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features), but I'm looking for something more along the lines of being built into the framework already, something where I can specify an SQL file with DDL to be loaded.

Comment: Or should I add something like DBUnit to my Grails app for this?

Comment: During the runtime of Unit Tests no tables are created, persistence is mocked. Integration Tests yes. Can you give some more details about what you are trying to achieve? There are many ways to do that, starting from using Bootstrap.groovy to using Database Migrations, but why do you need to create something outside of your domain model in Grails?

Comment: @MarcinNiebudek Yeah you're right my bad, I am talking about just Integration tests...Unit tests are supposed to test just one component and that component does not include a database as that portion should be mocked out.

Comment: @MarcinNiebudek The reason I wanted to create something outside of my domain model in Grails is because at the moment I do not know of any equivalent ORM frameworks that work on the offline database of an HTML5 browser.  If I want to achieve the ability to synchronize the data between the Grails App's online database, and the HTML5 local offline database, I can really only use Simple SQL if I want to simplify things and make sure that records in both the online and offline database are being accessed in a similar manner with similar queries and similar Entity Relationship Diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for something more along the lines of being built into the framework already, something where I can specify an SQL file with DDL to be loaded.

As far as I know, there is no such support built-into Grails, so you'll have to write it yourself. Luckily it shouldn't be too difficult. Here's an implementation plan:

- Store your DDL file in the conf directory
- In `Bootstrap.groovy`, dependency-inject the DataSource Spring bean
- In the `init` closure of `Bootstrap.groovy` use the DataSource to get a Connection to the DB
- Using the Connection, create the database and execute the SQL statements in the DDL file against it
- In the `destroy` closure of `Bootstrap.groovy`, drop the database

Comment: Ok, this sounds pretty straight forward.  Thanks Don! :)